# Packaging wallpapers for Ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center, desktop-background

I was wondering how to package some wallpapers into a package for the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: Do they have the appropriate licenses ?

Comment: I created them myself, so they are properly licensed. I am trying to figure out how to package them so I can add them to the software center.

Comment: Great idea!  Reply back in comments if you get a package out

Comment: Have you looked into using http://www.launchpad.com to publish your wallpapers? It is used by quite a lot of popular projects: Inkscape: https://launchpad.net/inkscape, Unity:https://launchpad.net/unity, MySQL: https://launchpad.net/mysql...just to name few!

Comment: It seems there are a number of steps involved in preparing software for the Ubuntu Software Center, more than what I am able to document here.  Perhaps [this Getting Started pdf](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/GettingStarted?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=playbook.pdf) will provide you with the answers you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a folder named whatever you want it to be. I recommend `wallpapers` in your home folder.

Inside this, create 2 folders: `DEBIAN` and `usr`

In the `usr` folder, create `share`. In that, create `wallpapers`. Put your wallpapers there.

In the `DEBIAN` folder, create 2 files: `control`, and `postinst`.

Then, make the control file look like:

```
Package: package name
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Maintainer: your name <your@email>
Architecture: all
Version: version number
Depends: whatever it depends on.
Description: a brief description of what your package includes or does.
<blank line here>
```

Note the blank line at the end, important!

Then, In `postinst`

```
#!/bin/bash

chmod a+r /usr/share/backgrounds/<wallpaper 1>
chmod a+r /usr/share/backgrounds/<wallpaper 2>
chmod a+r /usr/share/backgrounds/<wallpaper n>
# ...

exit 0
```

Do that for as many wallpapers as you have.

Save all the files.

Next, `sudo chown -R root.root ~/wallpapers/`

Finally, `sudo dpkg -b ~/wallpapers wallpaper.deb`

Then, you upload this to your PPA. Done!

src: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2034040